# Alternate grid background color in excel when a value of a single column changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I need a formula for conditional formatting to make an Excel 2010 spreadsheet alternate highlighting when a single column changes.  This question, "[How can I alternate grid background color in excel when a value of a single column changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/249190/how-can-i-alternate-grid-background-color-in-excel-when-a-value-of-a-single-colu)", is exactly what I want to do, but the suggested solution didn't work for me--it just highlights the first row of each matching value.

I know how to use conditional formatting, but for the life of me I can't figure out or find any pointers on the net so far to make this work.  Ideas?

Here is a link to a picture of how I want my spreadsheet to look when I'm done.  Basically I want every other Disp Number value row to be highlighted.  Seems like it would be a common thing to want to do, and I've seen this asked for in various places, but people struggle with making it work.

[Picture of desired end result](http://www.flickr.com/photos/climbing_yggdrasil/8485468089)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I alternate grid background color in excel when a value of a single column changes?](http://superuser.com/questions/249190/how-can-i-alternate-grid-background-color-in-excel-when-a-value-of-a-single-colu)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer is copied straight from stackoverflow.com [Alternating coloring groups of rows in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020/alternating-coloring-groups-of-rows-in-excel/6768304#6768304).

I use this formula to get the input for a conditional formatting:

```
=IF(B2=B1,E1,MOD(E1+1,2))    [content of cell E2]
```

Where column B contains the item that needs to be grouped and E is an auxiliary column. Every time that the upper cell (B1 on this case) is the same as the current one (B2), the upper row content from column E is returned. Otherwise, it will return that content plus 1 MOD 2 (that is, the outupt will be 0 or 1, depending on the value of the upper cell).

[image]

[image]

[image]

As an alternative to the MOD function, you could use 1 - E1. So full formula is `=IF(B2=B1,E1,1-E1)`.

A pretty similar method is described in [Color Banding Based On Content](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ContentBanding.aspx),
where a downloadable example is included.

Comment: I was thrown off at first because my version of Excel disliked the semicolons (with an enigmatic error message), but once I used commas in the formulas instead, this worked.

Comment: Semi-colons replaced above by commas.

Comment: The top image still shows semicolons.

Comment: Clever!  I like it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a whole lot simpler if you’re willing to create a couple of helper columns. 
For example, set `Y2` to `=($A2=$A1)`, set `Z1` to `TRUE`, set `Z2` to
`=IF($Y2, $Z1, NOT($Z1))`, and drag/fill `Y2:Z2` down to the last row where you have data. 
Column `Z` will alternate between `TRUE` and `FALSE` in the manner that you desire. 
Of course you can hide columns `Y` and `Z` when you’ve gotten it debugged.

In case this isn’t clear: the cell in column `Y` determines whether the values of `A` on this row and the preceding one are the same, so it is `FALSE` on the first row of each new value and then `TRUE` throughout the rest of the block.  And column `Z` is a chain of dominos –– each value depends on the one above it.  If the value in column `Y` is `TRUE`, `Z` keeps the same value as the row above; otherwise, `Z` switches.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is essentially the same solution as proposed by Harrymc, but only one helper column is really needed.  More info above.

Answer (score 1):

The helper column alternating 1 and 0 does not need a MOD() function.  A simple formula for E2 is -

```
=IF(B2=B1,E1,1-E1)
```