# Alternating color in visible rows based on column value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

This is similar to [Alternate grid background color in excel when a value of a single column changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/553899/alternate-grid-background-color-in-excel-when-a-value-of-a-single-column-changes) , and I believe it can be done using `SUBTOTAL(109,...` , but I can't quite figure it out.

The first column in my table is a group number, and all rows with the same group number should have the same background.  The table is sorted by the group number.

[image: First view]

I want to alternate the row color per group, based only on the visible rows.  In this example I've hidden `A` and `C` .  Note that `praesent` and `libero` have swapped colors based on the visible rows.

[image: Filtered view]

I'm free to add in hidden helper formula columns, but I'd prefer it all to be in the conditional formatting.

Comment: The only thing I'm concerned with is: In your example. When your cells are in a filter/subtotal. See your bottom image. Does Row(13), in a filter, count row(9) as being adjacent, or row(12)?

Comment: Row 13 counts row 9 as adjacent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer with two helper columns (of course you can hide them):

- helper1: `=AGGREGATE(2,5,A2)`

  - it just shows 1 for visible and 0 for invisible rows (of course you always see 1 :) )
- helper2: `=IF(C2=1,IFERROR(MAX($D$1:D1)+(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$C$1:C1,1)=0),1),"")`

  - `MAX($D$1:D1)` - looks for greatest group number so far
  - `COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$C$1:C1,1)` - checks whether current value is present in ABOVE VISIBLE rows
  - `MAX(...)+(COUNTIFS(...)=0)` - increases group number if it's a new group
  - `IFERROR(...,1)` - sets group number to 1 for first visible row
  - `IF(C2=1,...,"")` - calculates group number only for visible rows

Setting up conditional formatting:

- go to: Home - conditional formatting - new rule - use a formula...
- in formula enter `=MOD($D1,2)=1`
- set your desired formatting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm only adding this as an answer because I don't have enough rep to comment. This is based on Mate's answer which was awesome. I have condensed it to one helper column and made it rely on only values in consecutive rows (should help performance on large sets), and changed from count to counta (to let me use strings in addition to numbers).

=MOD(IF(D6<>D5,AGGREGATE(3,5,E6)+A5,A5),2)